# Image in Action bar without AppCompatActivity and with android:Theme.Holo.Light theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to place an image(ImageView) in top right corner of an Action bar. I don't want to use AppCompatActivity library and so my MainActivity extends Activity instead of AppCompatActivity. 
I use theme:  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">`

I tried with this code but it doesn't work because I don't extend AppCompatActivity:

```
 actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_imageview, null);

        v1 = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_imageview1, null);

        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

**EDIT:** I run this code on a device that runs Android 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a simple `Activity` you have to change this line

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

with ([check the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getActionBar()))

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
```

Comment: Now it works but I had to import `import android.app.ActionBar;`

Comment: @user101 mark the answer if it resolves the issue.It can help other users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toolbar for this. It is best option for you.Toolbar is a new standard replacement for ActionBar, introduced in Android Lollipop. It supports whole bunch of customization as you wish along with no or less modification to ActionBar logic.

Or you can use code :`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    mTitleTextView.setText("Title");

    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        //if you want..You can set action
        }
    });`
```

Comment: I develop this on 4.4.2 Android

Comment: @SanketPrahbu:  `actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` - > Cannot resolve method error.

Comment: I cannot use toolbar because I develop on Android 4.4.2 and not on Android 5.0.